# Compare/search Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to Excel tables. They are sorted after one attribute. Now I want to compare these tables. The problem is, my tables don't have the same values.

e.g.
Table 1
1
2
3
4
5
7
9

table 2
1
3
4
5
6
7
9

if I try to compare these fields hardcoded (IF(A1=B1;x;y)) i have some missing rows as soon as I get to 3 in Table2. So how am I able to search the table for this number and compare its corresponding row to the other?
Please no VB-skript ;)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you lay out your example data in tabular format so we can more clearly se the problem?
Edit your post and use the blockquote button to write in a fixed-width font

Comment: You can use a comparer software like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) (it's not free)

Comment: WinMerge is perfect for comparing Excel files, and it's free

Answer (score 1):

In both tables you can use a `=VLOOKUP()` to the other table to check for existance. If you are working with ranges that frequently change in size, you would create names.

Example:

- Workbook/Sheet1 contains values in A1 .. A5 .... you name this "MyData"
- Workbook/Sheet2 contains values in A1 .. A9 .... you name this "MyData"
- add into Sheet1.[B1] the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1,Book2.xls!MyData,1,FALSE)` and copy down
- add into Sheet2.[B1] the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1,Book1.xls!MyData,1,FALSE)` and copy down

in both books a #N/A in column B indicates a key that is not existing in the other file

You can use the `=LOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_vector,result_vector)` e.g in Sheet1 to retrieve a value from column `result_vector` (from Sheet2) where the value in `lookup_vector` (from Sheet2) matches the `lookup_value` (in Sheet1).

example in Sheet1 (looking at Sheet2-> Range [MyThirdColumn]: `=LOOKUP(A1;Book2.xls!MyData;Book2.xls!MyThirdColumn)`

In combination with the above `=VLOOKUP(....)` which determines if the key is found at all, you can retrieve (and further compare) attached values: `=if(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(....))),LOOKUP(....),"nope!")`

Hope that helps you develop your formula

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips for you depending on the version of Excel you are using :

- http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/duplicates-with-conditional-formatting.php
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx